# draw image in a pdf file iPad

Tags: image, ipad, pdf-generation

I would draw an image on a pdf file created by my iPad app.
How can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Open the pdf on your computer, take a screenshot. Open paint and then paste. Draw away!

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I would draw it inside my app.